# orderedDict vs pandas series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series, ordereddictionary

Still new to this, sorry if I ask something really stupid. What are the differences between a Python ordered dictionary and a pandas series?

The only difference I could think of is that an orderedDict can have nested dictionaries within the data. Is that all? Is that even true?

Would there be a performance difference between using one vs the other?

My project is a sales forecast, most of the data will be something like: {Week 1 : 400 units, Week 2 : 550 units}... Perhaps an ordered dictionary would be redundant since input order is irrelevant compared to Week#?

Again I apologize if my question is stupid, I am just trying to be thorough as I learn.

Thank you!

-Stephen

Comment: So far I have loved learning Pandas, but their documentation is not at all beginner friendly (aside from their "10 minutes to Pandas" which doesn't answer this question). I don't have a professor or colleagues to ask these sorts of questions, is this not the correct place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most importantly, `pd.Series` is part of the `pandas` library so it comes with a lot of added functionality - see `attributes` and `methods` as you scroll down the `pd.Series` [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html). This compares to `OrderDict`: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

For your use case, using `pd.Series` or `pd.DataFrame` (which could be a way of using `nested dictionaries` as it has an `index` and multiple `columns`) seem quite appropriate. If you take a look at the `pandas` docs, you'll also find quite comprehensive time series functionality that should come in handy for a project around weekly sales forecasts.

Since `pandas` is built on `numpy`, the specialized scientific computing package, performance is quite good.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't thought about the added functionality within pandas. This definitely helps me stay on the right course.

Answer (score 1):

Ordered dict is implemented as part of the python collections lib. These collection are very fast containers for specific use cases. If you would be looking for only dictionary related functionality (like order in this case) i would go for that. While you say you are going to do more deep analysis in an area where pandas is really made for (eg plotting, filling missing values). So i would recommend you going for pandas.Series.